# What is the benefit of creating an Oracle context over just granting package execution?

Tags: oracle, row-level-security

I have been programming oracle row-level security using DBMS_RLS for several years, but I have actually skipped creating contexts.  I have seen the intermittent recommendations to `CREATE CONTEXT` and now I'm trying to pull the trigger.

But I'm not seeing much benefit to a context at *session level*. I attach a package, but I still have to grant execute on it to any users I want to be able to use it. What am I missing?

As far as I can tell, the only thing that creating the context with the package is that the package can issue `DBMS_SESSION.SET_CONTEXT` naming that context.  After that a call to `SYS_CONTEXT` with that context will get the value set.

However, `SYS_CONTEXT` is itself kind of a hack.  It only returns a `VARCHAR2` rather than a typed value.  Why not just add a function to the same package with the right data type?

Anything I put into the context with the context package can also be available through that same package.

Now, creating a *global* context seems like it might have benefits sharing across sessions, except that's not my goal here.

Answer (score 0):

> But I'm not seeing much benefit to a context at session level. I attach a package, but I still have to grant execute on it to any users I want to be able to use it. What am I missing?

**Security**

IMHO - Using SYS_CONTEXT() (instead of a Package) is a Security thing.  The only way to set SYS_CONTEXT() values is through a Package.  This package will most likely have access to data that the user does not.

This extra access can be done by:

- Creating the Package as a Definer's Rights package
- Creating the Package as an Invoker's Rights package and [Grant it a Role (12.1+)](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/code-based-access-control-12cr1).

For extra security, the Context Package is not create in any of your DATA_SCHEMAs, CODE_SCHEMAs, or Parsing Schemas (eg the connected user or APEX Application Parsing Schema).  As such, I recommend you use place it in a separate "Security Schema".

Comment: Agree, but then all the benefit is from putting the package in a security schema, not from using it in a context.